# Custom Jenkins plugin doesn't remember it's own variables while re-configuring a job

Tags: jenkins-plugins

Created a simple custom Jenkins plugin. Used sqlplus-script-runner (SQLPlus Script Runner) as a prototype. Everything seems to be working. But I am facing a very strange trouble.
I drop my plugin into a job as a build step. Configure it filling each field. Save the job. And when I run it it works just fine. But...
If I need to modify the plugin parameters in that job and open it to reconfigure all my parameters come back blank. Completely wiped out.
Any hint will be highly appreciated.
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you need to define default values for your parameters. 
So if you dont set then value explicit your default value kicks in.

Answer (score 0):

I have to answer my own question. First I want to express my gratitude to Holleoman for such a quick response. But that was not the case. Cannot say for sure what have I done but it kinda cured it itself. One thing I can say for sure if that in order to resolve the issue I tried to use a class extending a BuildWrapper along Info and InfoWrapper classes. Where InfoWrapper was simply extending Info. Info in turn had @DataBoundConstructor annotated constructor etc. But that's irrelevant. B/c right after I got rid of those and went back to the original config everything started working as it should.
Sorry if it sounds confusing but I have nothing more to add. Other than between those attempts I have also noticed that Messages.properties, config.properties and global.properties files where not under "Resource bundle 'Messages'" and so on in my IntelliJ IDEA project.
If that's the case then I would say that's what solve the issue.
Sorry, there is nothing more to add.